# Serial Port Communication Using Java & RXTX in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, serial-port, rxtx

To write an java application to communicate with serial port devices on windows environment , browsed in google seem to be divert to many directions also fond some of the third party tools library like [RXTX](http://codeglobe.blogspot.in/2009/02/serial-port-communication-in-java.html)   [JavaComm](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11). On trying with RXTX sample codes using eclipse [Reference](http://code.google.com/p/museum-multimedia-solution/wiki/RxTx).

No serial ports were displayed in output just blank

Output :

> Stable Library
>
> Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
>
> Java lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7

What mistake  i have did ?

Let me know that is this approach is the better or suggest me better solution ?

Kindly let me know the alternatives for this problem , i wanna communicate with device via serial port using java, the data will be sent from the device  and it should be written to the files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code you are using?

Comment: Please see the reference link in mah posts @claymore1977

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the linked example *fails* it means that RXTX hasn't detected *any* serial ports on your machine. You may have a serial port on your machine but one of the reasons it isn't recognized by your OS *might* be because it is actually a serial-to-USB adapter, and is being recognized as  an USB port.

If you are on Linux, serial ports usually look like this:

```
ls /dev/ttyS*
```

outputs:

```
/dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyS1
/dev/ttyS2
```

the adapted port might look like this:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

If you can see some output on your serial attached device (e.g. POS printer or LCD display) you can test it like this:

```
echo 'hello' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and the device should show the 'hello' string if it is attached to that port and everything is working properly.

However, I would definitely recommend [Java simple serial connector](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) library over RxTx. We have tried both in an commercial POS application (>1M tickets at this time).

RxTx is being used for sequential printing successfully. In the print scenario the RxTx library was called upon sequentially and used only to send the data *to the port*. Only some serial flags were red the detect to buissiness of the device.

But because of its limitations we simply could not use it for reading input from a serially connected IButton. In the iButton scenario the data is expected to be received asynchronously *from the port*. There were constant bugs and hangs when we tried to implement it with RxTx, but with JSSC it was implemented almost immediatley.