# How to solve error java.io.IOException: Input/output error in nativeavailable for Serial Communication?

Tags: java, rxtx, serial-communication

I have Arm processor which is AllWinner A13 ,RAM- 512mb, and OS- Linaro 13.01 Ubuntu (means debian). Now i m making Serial Communication program for /dev/ttyS0. i made simple program for Two Way Serial Communication in java with netbeans. In my processor i short rx-tx of ttyS0 for loop back coonection checking. Means what ever i send through Serial port that i get return back. but i get error. i installed openjdk-7, librxtx-java on my processor. my code and error is below. If any have idea or solution then please suggest to me.

```
package serialcomm_linaro;


import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class TwoWaySerialComm
{
    public TwoWaySerialComm()
    {
        super();
    }

    void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
    {
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
        if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
        }
        else
        {
            CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

            if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
            {
                SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

                InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

                (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
                (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
            }
        }     
    }

    /** */
    public static class SerialReader implements Runnable 
    {
        InputStream in;

        public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
        {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public void run ()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = -1;
            try
            {
                while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
                {
                    System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));
                }
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
        }
    }

    /** */
    public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable 
    {
        OutputStream out;

        public SerialWriter ( OutputStream out )
        {
            this.out = out;
        }

        public void run ()
        {
            try
            {                
                int c = 0;
                while ( ( c = System.in.read()) > -1 )
                {
                    this.out.write(c);
                }                
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            (new TwoWaySerialComm()).connect("/dev/ttyS0");
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

my out is below . In this out i just send 123 and i get return back 23 first and then 1111... more time, and then errore. Instead of 111111.... i want only return back 123.

```
enter code here
RXTX Warning:  Removing stale lock file. /var/lock/LCK..ttyS0
123
23
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111



java.io.IOExcepti on: Input/output error in nativeavailable
        at gnu.io.RXTXPort.nativeavailable(Native Method)
        at gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.read(RXTXPort.java:1429)
        at gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.read(RXTXPort.java:1341)
        at serialcomm_linaro.TwoWaySerialComm$SerialReader.run(TwoWaySerialComm.java:66)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hadn't tried serial communication over RXTX in a loopback scenario, but that shouldn't matter. The only thing that looks a bit suspicious is the part where you give the instance of the input stream to the `SerialReader`. I recommend that you pass `SerialPort` instance to both constructors, and every time you need to read from/write to the port's stream, use a stream getter, e.g. for reading:

```
 public static class SerialReader implements Runnable 
{
    SerialPort serialPort;

    public SerialReader ( SerialPort serialPort )
    {
        this.serialPort = serialPort;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = -1;
        try
        {
            while ( ( len = serialPort.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > -1 )
            {
                System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
}
```

please feedback.

UPDATE:

From my personal [experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018438/serial-port-communication-using-java-rxtx-in-eclipse/14100653#14100653) RXTX is a buggy solution. This however does not mean that this situation is caused by an underlying RXTX bug. It might be because the serial port isn't setup correctly, but in your case it is a standard port name with standard connection parameters. As a loooong shot, try replacing the baudrate 115200 with 9600, but that probably won't help. I can offer three paths from here:

- try debugging the RXTX code - you might get more insight on what's happening
- read the [serial line troubleshooting](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk713/tk628/technologies_tech_note09186a00800a758d.shtml)
- consider other Java solutions for serial communication, like [JSSC](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) instead of RXTX.

UPDATE:

I'm afraid I have been inattentive and jumped ahead. JSSC native libraries (.so,.dll) are inside the jssc.jar so they are loaded "automatically". With RXTX they come outside the jar file so you need to set the `java.library.path` system property in order for the JVM to find and load them or you'll get an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

You can open the JSSC jar file by a double click, and it will open in an archiver because it is [actually a zip file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)). As with RXTX, you will notice that the native libs files are organized in directories named like operating systems (windows, linux, RXTX has Mac_OS_X and Solaris also).

Inside these directories there are the native libs files, the .so, dll., and .jnilib types of files, which are named after [computer architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture). That's the broader meaning of the word, these are short codes for [instruction set architectures (ISA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture). The instruction set defines the set of instructions (commands) for a CPU. In other words, there are many different CPU models (like your AllWinner A13) that conform to the same instruction set. The native libs source code is compiled to produce the executables (.so,...) which is a bunch of instructions from that same instruction set.

The reason why you got the UnsatisfiedLinkError with JSSC  *might* be because you're on an unsupported architecture, and the corresponding native lib is being is searched for in an unexistent directory. The ISA short codes, which are also the names of these directories for JSSC are [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/x86) and [PPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ppc) architectures, both 32 and 64 bit variant. RXTX has many other's but I think that none of them is equivalent to [ARMv7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) which is the ISA of your [AllWinner A13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allwinner_A13) CPU.

You can determine your [architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) by executing  this command in terminal:

```
uname -m
```

On my linux it ouputs:

```
x86_64
```

which means that it is a [64bit Intel 8086 architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86). Both JSSC and RXTX have implemented this architecture. If your architecture isn't implemented (supported) than you can't use these libraries to connect to serial port on that computer. In that case you must write your own or obtain a suitable implementation.

If the architecture matches and there are still native errors you might try [recompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696300/how-to-compile-c-under-ubuntu-linux) the native libs sources. The sources are provided for both [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/pub/rxtx/rxtx-2.1-7r2.zip) and [JSSC](https://java-simple-serial-connector.googlecode.com/files/jSSC-0.9.0-Release.zip).

UPDATE:

If your architecture is `armv7l` that means that JSSC, RXTX and [JavaComm](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java#JavaComm_API) (approximatley said, RXTX "ancestor") in their current state are useless in your scenario.

I didn't manage to find any other open source java library for serial communication. If that is really true, you'd need to write your own native library conforming to the interface of the one of the above libraries to make them useful. In other words, you'd need to write a [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) program (something like this: [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/218934/Serial-Port-Programming-in-Linux.aspx#answer1), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/220479/Reading-SMS-messages-from-sim-via-serial-port-in-L.aspx#answer1)) with functionality of [serial communication](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/2AD81B9060162E708625678C006DFC62) and [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) interface to the Java library.

In the sense of the answer completness, I'll mention a commercial product [SerialIO](http://www.serialio.com/) which does support some ARM architectures (don't know if your is one of them). But if you decide for that solution, you can always send a query to their support.

Comment: thanks for reply. here i use loop back scenario for testing that what ever i send through serial port that is return back to me. before use this program in laser and x-ray part i have to check and test it very well.

Comment: i tried according to you said but still  that old error is occurred.

Comment: thanks for early reply for helping to me. now i will try your options one by one.

Comment: i got errore when try to use jSSC-0.9.0-Release.zip (jssc.jar). i extract that jssc folder and use jssc.jar into my javaApp on ubuntu and it gives error like      run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Ljava/lang/String;)I
 at jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Native Method)
 at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:143)
 at serialcomm_linaro.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: [UnsatifsfiedLinkError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) means that the code tries to use some external libraries (.so for linux, .dll for windows) but can't find them. You need to find the dir where those files and set it as system property. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543202/rxtx-installation-on-windows-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-gnu-io-commport/12808713#12808713) how. But that's odd, the last time I used it that wasn't necessary. I'll have to take a look, and please feedback.

Comment: i used jSSC-0.9.0-Release in myApp. but in jSSC-0.9.0-Release (version), there is nothing like any .dll or .so file. i know where to put .jar file and .so file in linux. i also put that jssc.jar in /usr/lib/jvm/openJdk-7/jre/lib/ext/jssc.jar and .so file for this path /usr/lib/jvm/openJdk-7/jre/lib/arm/  . but i have no .so file of jssc . So, where i can get(or download) .so file of jSSC-0.9.0-Release version and arm processor ? please help me.

Comment: I have answered your question. Please feedback, what is your architecture?

Comment: thanks for helping to me. sorry for late my reply. i run command uname -m on my amr processore and i get answer is    

armv7l.

Comment: @Jay so how did it end? implemented, bought or gave up? or? :)

Comment: There is rxtx works well. Main problem is that my serial port of arm processor is in debugging mode. so i change in my script file and its works fine with RXTx. i install rxtx using this command . sudo apt-get install librxtx-java.thanks for help to me and suggest to me , you give new idea to think in deffierent way.

Comment: glad it worked out! np, you are welcome, I also learned :) Had no idea that RXTX has their native libs in linux repos!